# CMake EXTERNALPROJECT_ADD does not trigger build when (external project) source is changed

Tags: c++, cmake

Well, as far as I understand from looking for the issue here and there, it actually shouldn't. Instead people suggest using `ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET` instead. So, I switched from this:

```
EXTERNALPROJECT_ADD(spdk
                    SOURCE_DIR ${EXTDIR}/spdk
                    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./configure ${SPDK_CONFIG}
                    BUILD_COMMAND $(MAKE) -j CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} CXX=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} DPDK_CFLAGS=${DPDK_CONFIG}
                    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
                    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
                    LOG_CONFIGURE 1
                    LOG_BUILD 1
                    )
```

To this:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(spdk-configure
                  COMMAND ./configure ${SPDK_CONFIG}
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${EXTDIR}/spdk
                  )

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(spdk
                  COMMAND $(MAKE) -j CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} CXX=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} DPDK_CFLAGS=${DPDK_CONFIG}
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${EXTDIR}/spdk
                  )

ADD_DEPENDENCIES(spdk spdk-configure)
```

However, I see the `spdk/spdk-configure` are built each time I invoke the build, regardless if the target is up to date, which, maybe undesired, but [documented behavior](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html).

> The target has no output file and is always considered out of date
>   even if the commands try to create a file with the name of the target.

I'm less than happy with this behavior, is there any additional option that may be more appropriate for the above case?

EDIT001:
Looks like it is not really building anything on second run. It simply takes ages until make rescans all targets